# How to read response headers in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-http

My server returns this kind of header: `Content-Range:0-10/0`:

[image]

I tried to read this header in angular with no luck:

```
var promise = $http.get(url, {
    params: query
}).then(function(response) {
  console.log(response.headers());
  return response.data;
});
```

which just prints

```
Object {content-type: "application/json; charset=utf-8"}
```

Any ideas how to access the content range header?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Use the `headers` variable in success and error callbacks

[From documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http).

```
$http.get('/someUrl').
  success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
  })
  .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
  });
```

If you are on the same domain, you should be able to retrieve the response headers back. If cross-domain, you will need to add [`Access-Control-Expose-Headers`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) header on the server.

```
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: content-type, cache, ...
```

Comment: This still does not give me the response headers, just the request headers.

Comment: I have cross-domain enabled already. The screenshot in my question shows that the content-range header is inside the response in the chrome inspector. So the server is not the problem.

Comment: Yes, CORS returns certain headers by default. And you need to tell it which other headers are safe to be exposed via the api. [See this](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#access-control-expose-headers-response-header).

Comment: The success call seems to be deprecated and shouldn't be used. Check docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: THIS DOES NOT WORK ANYMORE! see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41169385/http-get-success-is-not-a-function

Comment: will it work to fetch set-cookie(with httponly flag) from response header?

Answer (score 34):

Why not simply try this:

```
var promise = $http.get(url, {
    params: query
}).then(function(response) {
  console.log('Content-Range: ' + response.headers('Content-Range'));
  return response.data;
});
```

Especially if you want to return the `promise` so it could be a part of a promises chain.

Comment: Giving a (+1) because `response` has a `headers()` method which takes a `name` parameter. This is my issue though; I cannot retrieve `Authorization` header [or any others] via `response.headers('Authorization')` even when I can see `response.config.headers['Authorization']` in plain sight!!! What is the world is this function for then???

Comment: Is it a cross-domain request?

Comment: You should probably not work with the A‌​uthorization in a single request like this. Use an interceptor for Authorization stuff

Comment: @EugeneRetunsky : I have cross domain request. I can see the authorization header in response, but now able to fetch it. Anyway I can do that as API is returning token for successful authentication.

Comment: i'm getting "headers is not a function"

Comment: `Authorization` is a common _request_ header.  I have never seen it as a response header.  Are you sure it's actually in your response?  The `response.config.headers` may be referring to the request, not the response.

Answer (score 12):

Updated based on Muhammad's answer...

```
$http.get('/someUrl').
  success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
    console.log(headers()['Content-Range']);
  })
  .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
  });
```

Answer (score 7):

Additionally to Eugene Retunsky's answer, quoting from [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) documentation regarding the response:

> The response object has these properties:
>
> - **data** – `{string|Object}` – The response body transformed with the transform functions.
> - **status** – `{number}` – HTTP status code of the response.
> - **headers** – `{function([headerName])}` – Header getter function.
> - **config** – `{Object}` – The configuration object that was used to generate the request.
> - **statusText** – `{string}` – HTTP status text of the response.

Please note that the argument callback order for [$resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) (v1.6) **is not the same** as above:

> Success callback is called with `(value (Object|Array), responseHeaders (Function), status (number), statusText (string))` arguments, where the value is the populated resource instance or collection object. The error callback is called with `(httpResponse)` argument.

Answer (score 2):

```
response.headers();
```

will give you all the headers (defaulat & customs). worked for me !!

[image]

[image]

**Note** .    I tested on the same domain only. We may need to add `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` header on the server  for cross domain.

Answer (score 1):

The response headers in case of cors remain hidden.
You need to add in response headers to direct the Angular to expose headers to javascript.

```
// From server response headers :
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, 
Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, X-Custom-header");
header("Access-Control-Expose-Headers: X-Custom-header");
header("X-Custom-header: $some data");

var data = res.headers.get('X-Custom-header');
```

Source : https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5237

Answer (score 1):

According the MDN custom headers are not exposed by default. The server admin need to expose them using "Access-Control-Expose-Headers" in the same fashion they deal with "access-control-allow-origin"

See this MDN link for confirmation
[https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Expose-Headers]