# Get response headers of post request in angular

Tags: angularjs, http-headers

I'm trying to make a simple post request in Angular and acquire the response the headers. The problem is I get this response for the header:

```
function (d){b||(b=fd(a));return d?(d=b[G(d)],void 0===d&&(d=null),d):b}
```

**Angular code:**

```
$http.get(url).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    callback(data, status, headers, config);
});
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Is this for a cross-domain request?

Comment: Yes it is a cross-domain request.

Comment: ok, see the answer here - http://stackoverflow.com/a/28805641/3055401 - you may need to add a `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` header on the server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My colleague found the answer:
the response was a function so should therefore be run as a function.
So to get the value of the headers I used this:

```
$scope.results = headers();
```

Answer (score 0):

AngularJs v1.7.5

```
 $http({
      ...
      }).then(function success(data) {
            var heder=data.headers();
         }
```