# angularjs read request header

Tags: angularjs, single-sign-on, request-headers, angular-http-interceptors

We have a angularjs site which is SSO protected and deployed on our apache webserver.

- Once the user is authenticated and authorized for access - the SSO
  agent would enrich the http header section with relevant user
  information and forward the request to the angular site.
- Based on the presence of the authorization parameters in the header
  the user will be taken to the home page.

My question is regarding the approach and the best practices.

1. How do we read the request headers that are being sent to the
   angularjs application. I have created a interceptor which can read
   the header information but am not sure if that approach is correct.
2. Question related to approach - What is the recommended best practice to
       handle such scenario - i have a angular website residing on
       webserver and an REST api project. The website and REST communicates
       using an api key for security.

Appreciate all your responses.

Comment: Pradeepta, as you used you are using REST API , why cant you store that request header in the scope and display acorss all pages

Comment: @NagaSaiA Thanks for the response. I guess you are responding to the second part of the questions related to best practices. Yes I can store the header within the angular app and use that to communicate with the REST API. I am not sure how within angular application would i be able to read the HTTP header elements that would be passed on from the SSO.

Comment: Pradeepa, this might help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28805589/how-to-read-response-headers-in-angularjs