# How can i access the response header in .then function AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, header

do you know how i can access the response header from a get request ?

I have a service function which return a promise. My Controller resolve the promise and in .then function i need the content type from the response header.

I have try to use the "headers" parameter, which i display with console.log(headers()), but the error "headers() is not a function" shown in my console.

My Service :

```
.factory('GetResultFile',
['$http', '$q',
function ($http, $q) {

    var service = {};
    service.getResult = function(id, rid) {

        var deferred = $q.defer();

        $http
        .get('http://localhost:9999/v1/jmeter/' + id + '/results/' + rid, {cache: false})
        .then(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            if(data.status == 200) {
                console.log(data.status);
                deferred.resolve(data);
            }
            else {
                deferred.reject(data);
            }
        });
        return deferred.promise;                
    }
    return service;
```

}]);

controller:

```
$scope.getResult = function(rid) {
        console.log($scope.id);
        GetResultFile.getResult($scope.id, rid)
        .then(function(data, headers) {
            //console.log(headers.Content-type);
            console.log(headers());
            console.log(data);
            console.log("Download succeed");
            console.log(data.status);

            var file = new Blob([data.data], {type: 'text/plain;charset=utf-8'});
            FileSaver.saveAs(file, 'test.txt');

        }, function (data) {
            console.log("Download ERROR!");
            console.log(data.status);
        })
    };
```

}])

Comment: Could you please add the code of your service.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read response headers in angularjs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28805589/how-to-read-response-headers-in-angularjs)

Comment: i updated my answer.

@MoshFeu oh, i will check the post

Comment: @kai Check my Answer and accept it please If it satisfies you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Without some more Info I can only think about the Standard things like

```
    this.$http.get('/your/Route')
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response) // Full information
        console.log(response.data) // holds your Data
        console.log(response.config) // holds more Specific information like the Url and more
        console.log(response.headers());// Specific headers Information
        console.log(response.headers(["content-type"]));//gets the Content-Type of Header

});
```

Generally to Angular Service and Response

> The response object has these properties:
>
> - **data** – `{string|Object}` – The response body transformed with the transform functions.
> - **status** – `{number}` – HTTP status code of the response.
> - **headers** – `{function([headerName])}` – Header getter function.
> - **config** – `{Object}` – The configuration object that was used to generate the request.
> - **statusText** – `{string}` – HTTP status text of the response.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: hi,

thank you for the answer. One question : how can i check the content type from the response header ? 

console.log(headers([content-type]) ?

Comment: @Kai Yeah just do `console.log(response.headers(["content-type"]));`. Will Edit my Answer with that Solution

Comment: thank you, i have try it with console.log(response.header('content-type'))

works fine !