# How to redirect users to another page with Angular routing if the API controller has Authorize attribute?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, angular-routing, asp.net-authorization

I have such Api action method:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
[HttpGet, Route("")]
public List<TaskViewModel> GetAll()
{
    return TasksRepository.SelectAll(Context);
}
```

and using angular to fetch data through some http service;
and have this routing configuration:

```
 $routeProvider.when('/Tasks', {
        title: 'Tasks',
        controller: 'tCtrlr',
        templateUrl: '../HTML/Tasks.html',
    })
```

The problem with that approach is that I cant notify the user that he is getting an empty data because he is not authorized to view its content?
so I want to show a message or redirect him to another page, if the API action has Authorize attribute, that the user must be logged in or he cannot view the contents of the page?

Answer (score 0):

You"ll have to check the response header ..
If the status is 401 (unauthorized) then handle the redirection or else

Try something like this

```
$http("api/yourAPI")
.then(function (success) { ... }  ,
function (error) {
if (error.status==401) {
// handle unauthorised 
}
});
```

I'm not quite sure about syntax but you got the idea

**Edit**    for Refrence
Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28805589/how-to-read-response-headers-in-angularjs) for more clear syntax  but keep in mind that .success .error are deprecated in angularjs latest version